how to query inventory card based on product master in mysql
I have 2 tables (Product master, and transactions table)
Product table:



PID
PName
Active




P-0001
BT mouse
True


P-0002
BT Keyboard
True


P-0003
BT Earphone
True



transaction table:



Trans_ID
Trans_Date
PID
Qty
Category




T-240101
2024-01-01
P-0001
10
IN


T-240101
2024-01-01
P-0002
20
IN


T-240103
2024-01-03
P-0001
5
IN


T-240103
2024-01-04
P-0002
1
IN


T-240104
2024-01-04
P-0002
3
OUT


T-240105
2024-01-05
P-0002
1
IN



I need the query to select item mutation from start date to end date from all product master, for example:
i want to select item mutation from 2024-01-01 to 2024-01-31 the result should like this:



PID
Trans_Date
B_Balance
M_IN
M_OUT
E_Balance




P-0001
2024-01-01
0
10
0
10


P-0001
2024-01-03
10
0
5
5


P-0002
2024-01-01
0
20
0
20


P-0002
2024-01-04
20
1
3
18


P-0002
2024-01-05
18
1
0
19


P-0003
2024-01-01
0
0
0
0



the P-0003 must display even has no transaction, but show 0 to all mutation since it has no transaction.
can anyone help with the query in mysql? thank you in advance.

??? Transaction  table, row 3 - direction IN, desired output - direction OUT.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question  paragraph 5 - read and perform

What have you tried so far? If you have not tried anything, then the keywords to get you started are: running total and cumulative sum.
